# registers/thread says 50 but they are actually 56

Tags: cuda

I'm using CUDA 5.5, VS2010 and parameters compute_35 and sm_35. I have a GFX Titan.

I have a kernel which Registers/Thread says it uses 50 registers, threads per block are 128 and registers/block are 7168.

7168 / 128 = 56.

I'm not using textures.

See the below image:

[image: registers]

If I limit the register usage to 48 I get this:
47 registers/thread but actually usage is 48 per thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All architectures have a register file allocation granularity. In practice this means that the number of allocated registers per warp or block must be rounded up to the next largest multiple of the register page size.

For your GTX titan, the register file allocation size is 256 registers and the allocation unit is per warp. So using your example:

```
50 registers per thread = 50 * 32 = 1600 registers per warp
1600 registers per warp / 256 registers per page = 7 pages per warp
7 pages per warp = 7 * 256 = 1792 registers per warp
128 threads per block = 4 warps per block = 4 * 1792 = 7168 registers per block
```

thus one block of your kernel requires 7168 registers, even though the number of registers per thread * threads per block only gives 6400 registers. You can see all these numbers in the occupancy spreadsheet that ships with every version of the CUDA toolkit.

Comment: Registers/Thread comes from the compiler output through the CUDA driver. Registers/Block as Talonmies explained accounts for the register allocation granularity which is 256 registers/warp (8 register/thread). The first number is the registers per thread used by the code. The second is the allocation size. In most cases this will never vary by more than RegisterAllocationGranualarityPerThread - 1. For extreme simple kernels ABI compliance may result in a minimum register allocation of 16 registers/thread.